# vertical-align middle and text-align center on absolute div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a certain width and height. In that div I also have a text. I want to align that text to the center (horizontally) and to the middle (vertically). But the div also needs a `position: absolute`. So it can be positioned inside another div.

But because of the `absolute` the text won't align vertically anymore.

This is what I have:

```
<div style="z-index:20;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dotted #16232d;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    top:88px; left:31px;
    display: table-cell;
    line-height: normal;
    font-size:32px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/s8jp5ohh/

The text will never contain any `<br>`. So it's always one line. But it should automatically break to a new line when the text is larger than the width of the div. So I'd like to keep that functionality (like you can see in the fiddle).

Is there a way to align the text in the center, vertically and horizontally?

Comment: This has been answered before

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div

Comment: What you want can not be accomplished with css alone. Closest thing you can come to it is have a wrapper to display:table and your div to display:table-cell. The vertical alignment will work, as will the horizontal one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will solve it : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/s8jp5ohh/14/)**

**css**

```
.myDiv {
    z-index:20;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dotted #16232d;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    top:88px;
    left:31px;
    line-height: normal;
    font-size:32px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}
.myDiv p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a hack, but it works:

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/s8jp5ohh/20/)

HTML

```
<div class="block" style="z-index:20;
position: absolute;
border: 1px dotted #16232d;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
line-height: 200px;
top:88px; left:31px;
display: table-cell;
line-height: normal;
font-size:32px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;">
    <p style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit    amet</p>
```

CSS:

```
.block:before {
    content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}
```